# make dictionaries from list with multiple values for each key

Tags: python, loops, file, dictionary

We need to make two dictionaries, one for prices and another for quantities from the same text file called Initial_inventory-1.txt. Both dictionaries will have the product name as the key in the dictionary.

My output gives a dictionary with the names, prices, and then the first letter of the name and I don't know why. It happens for both dictionaries.

```
def read_file(file_name, prices, quantities):
    file = open(file_name, 'r')

    for line in file:
        product = line.strip('\n').split(';')
        name, price = product[0], product[1]
        prices[name] = price
        for price in product[0]:
            prices.setdefault(price, []).append(name)
        name, quantity = product[0], product[2]
        quantities[name] = quantity
        for quantity in product[0]:
            quantities.setdefault(quantity, []).append(name)
        
            
    print(prices)
    print(quantities)
```

main function:

```
def main():
    #init dictionaries
    prices = {}
    quantities = {}
    #read_file
    read_file("initial_inventory-1.txt", prices, quantities)
main()
```

There is more to the assignment, which is why they are in those functions, I CANNOT get rid of them. Thank you in advance!

Comment: `product[0]` is a string. What do you think `for price in product[0]` does?

Comment: Try printing out `name` and `price` after assigning them and maybe you'll see the problem on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`product[0]` is the product name, which is a string. When you iterate over that, you're iterating over the characters in the name.

The keys of the `prices` and `quantities` dictionaries should be the `name`. You should use that as the first argument to `setdefault()`. You shouldn't assign to the dictionary first, that's replacing the list of prices and quantities with this price and quantity.

```
def read_file(file_name, prices, quantities):
    file = open(file_name, 'r')

    for line in file:
        name, price, quantity = line.strip('\n').split(';')
        prices.setdefault(name, []).append(price)
        quantities.setdefault(name, []).append(quantity)
        
            
    print(prices)
    print(quantities)
```